# Use OLED Taskbar Transparency in 1803

Tags: taskbar, windows-10-v1803

I like the super transparent taskbar very much. However, this registry tweak seems to no longer work in Win10 v1803:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency"=dword:00000001
```

Can I have it in Win10 v1803?

Comment: There's software that can do it. Probably can be done using Classic Shell too.

Comment: StartIsBack++ allows tweaking taskbar theming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've exactly the same problem and found the solution.

There is a software package out there called "TranslucentTB" and that worked for me (build version windows 1803)

https://github.com/TranslucentTB/TranslucentTB/releases

When you downloaded it and start it, it comes with a few options. Like blur (default) and clear.

It shows up as a taskbar icon on the right. right click it and enable "open at boot" and choose your setting. I choose clear.

Then In the colors section of windows personalization settings enable:

- Automatically pick an accent color from my background
- Transparency effects
- start, taskbar and action center
- title bars

All of this comes really close the what it was with UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency

I know apps like classic shell can do this too, but I find them too invasive. they change too much. besides we don't live in 2009 anymore.

Comment: I use this software too and it's awesome! Also, good answer!

Comment: Since I'm using this small application for now, I'm marking this answer as "accepted-pro-tempore".

Answer (score -1):

No, that's unavailable starting from Windows 10 version 1803. But Aero Glass feature is coming back.

Comment: Aero Glass is coming back? Where? If not, when?

Comment: check the edited new post: settings -> Personalization -> Colors,

Comment: No that option has been available for a *long* time and is absolutely not what I'm asking.

Comment: This is good information Karen, but is there official documentation or a source you can cite that indicates this? Including such a source will improve your answer by adding the weight of official and provable fact to it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the new setting is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize]
"EnableTransparency"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Nope. Its effect is not the same as `UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency`.